# face detection and make it blur

Tags: matlab, blur, face-detection, matlab-cvst

I am having trouble understanding the code about the Matlab

```
a = imread('Untitled2.png');
faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;
bbox=step(faceDetector,a);
for j=1:size(bbox)
    xbox=bbox(j,:);
    subImage = imcrop(a, xbox);
    H = fspecial('disk',10);
    blurred = imfilter(subImage,H);
    a(xbox(2):xbox(2)+xbox(4),xbox(1):xbox(1)+xbox(3),1:end) = blurred; 
end
imshow(a);
```

Can anyone please kindly explain me that what is the for loop doing? I tried to use my own method to blur the face that I detected, but I just manage to crop out the face and blur the cropped image but I don't know how to put it back to original image. Then I tried to use the source code above I get from internet and the internet source code is able to blur the face and I can't understand the for loop logic. Kindly please explain to me, T^T.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [there](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.cascadeobjectdetector-class.html) :

*BBOX = step(detector,I) returns BBOX, an M-by-4 matrix defining M bounding boxes containing the detected objects. This method performs multiscale object detection on the input image, I. Each row of the output matrix, BBOX, contains a four-element vector, [x y width height], that specifies in pixels, the upper-left corner and size of a bounding box. The input image I, must be a grayscale or truecolor (RGB) image.*

Are you sure that it's `j=1:size(bbox)` and not `j=1:size(bbox,1)` in the code?

Basically, The definition of BBox speaks by itself. The loop just iterates over all the boxes detected..

You then extract the informations about the j*th* box.

Then you extract the subImage given the position and size of xbox (xbox is a vector containing [x y width height]).

Then you define you filter.

Then you blur your subImage.

Then you override you image a with the blurred subimage using the informations in xbox.

EDIT : If you've already suceeded in blurring the cropped image, you just need to override you input image with your blurred image!